# Boolean vs optional true

Tags: typescript

What is a better way to describe some flag that can be in 'checked' or 'unchecked' state?

```
interface OperationResult {
    success?: true
}

interface OperationResult {
    success: boolean
}
```

Comment: What do you mean, "better way"? How are you going to use this? If you just write `if(myOperation.result) { ... }` then it doesn't matter.

Comment: I know TS syntax and understand that. And yes, for me it doesn't matter. That's why I am not sure which one to use and that's why I am asking here. Maybe somebody will share experience or best practice

Comment: go for second version

Comment: For a boolean it doesn't matter that much. But overall, I noticed that using optional values are much harder to debug and track, than "required" ones. Therefore I'd go with the latter one. Also, I guess you want to have it ON or OFF and not an additional third option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a semantic difference - with `success?: true` you mark the `success` flag as optional (potentially `undefined`) and "activatable" (`true`),  whereas `success: boolean` denotes a required property, which can be enabled xor disabled.

With upcoming TS 3.7 [Nullish Coalescing](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-3-7-rc/#nullish-coalescing) operator, these different semantics become even more apparent:

```
interface OperationResult { success?: true }
interface OperationResult2 { success: boolean }

declare const optionalFlag: OperationResult
declare const requiredFlag: OperationResult2

// t1 can potentially be assigned "yep", if optionalFlag is null/undefined
let t1 = optionalFlag ?? "yep"; 

// t2 will always be assigned requiredFlag, can never be "yep" type-wise
let t2 = requiredFlag ?? "yep";
```

If you use `success?: true` and just want a required boolean `success` flag, you rely on implicit JavaScript Type Conversions/ [falsy values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy). In this case `success: boolean` would be a better choice, as it makes things explicit and does not leave room for misinterpretations for both the interpreter and your coworkers.

Answer (score 4):

The proper approach in modeling types is to try to use the smallest type which can fullfill the need. What I mean is, if you have a property `rank: string` and you know that rank can have only value from few possible options, then better will be to replace broader type `string` into the type which contains these exactly options. This can be done by string literal or enum, consider - `rank: 'captain' | 'general' | 'major'`. The benefit is that when you do different behavior, so logic which is related to this field, then you don't use magic strings, but u have type safety in terms of what can be there as a value, any typo is at this point impossible.

Lets get back to your question and how my paragraph is related to that.

```
// 1 - custom union of two values belonging to different types
interface OperationResult {
    success?: true // type is true | undefined
}
// 2 - native union, type boolean
interface OperationResult {
    success: boolean // type is boolean = true | false
}
```

The second is more accurate because it uses the primary union type existing in the language, so we use the simplest possible option - boolean, which is a type with two possible values. First option also uses a type with two possible values, but this is custom union. Both approaches are isomorphic ( we can replace one by another ), because clearly the relation is - `false` is represented by `undefined` and `true` is represented by `true`. First option is not superior over the second one, its equal, but introduce second binary type instead of boolean, which is really not wanted, I mean there is no reason for that.

Next issue of the approach with `true | undefined` is that every function which worked with boolean will not work with this new union. Of course undefined is falsy value and if you put this in `if` it will work, but under the hood we have type coercion, which is really not needed, as we can just use boolean which has the same properties.

To sum it up, if you need a data structure which has two states, boolean is the thing for the job, if you have a structure with more than two states, on this level you should replace boolean by something different like sum type. But there is no reason to replace native binary type by custom one.

Answer (score 2):

This depends on the situation, if you want to make an optional prop (a prop which could be passed down but is not required) you could use

```
interface OperationResult {
    success?: true
}
```

here you could or could not pass `success` down, doesn't matter.

If you want to use a prop which is required and could either be `false` or `true` use

```
interface OperationResult {
    success: boolean
}
```

In this case you are obligated to pass `success` down as either `true` or `false`.

Although functionally there won't be any difference, it's mostly preference aside from these minor differences.